# How add a row in table when user click on a gmap?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to add gmap to my app.I have on the page table and div with map, and I want to make sure that the user when add marker on the map - in table add one row.

there is my script (default script from google example)

```
 window.onload = function() {
     var mapOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000),
         zoom: 5,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {

         var location = e.latLng;

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: location,
             map: map
         });

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
             var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                 content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br />Longitude: ' + location.lng()
             });
             infoWindow.open(map, marker);
         });
     });
 };
```

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Google example you provided, you would do it after the line

```
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
```

You could insert something like

```
$('myTable').append('<tr><td>THIS IS MY NEW ROW</td></tr>');
```

depending on what your "row" should hold.